# explanation of matrix - augmented reality browser using android

Tags: android, accelerometer, augmented-reality, android-sensors

I am developing augmented reality camera application in which nearby locations would be augmented on the camera screen. I need to find the orientation of device. I am using accelerometer sensor with magnetic sensor. And i am learning all these from the code which is on github.

- I am unable to understand this [matrix class.](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality/blob/master/Pro%20Android%20AR%209/src/com/paar/ch9/Matrix.java) **Can anyone please
  tell me what are a1,a2,.....c2,c3 ?**

  private volatile float a1=0f, a2=0f, a3=0f;

  private volatile float b1=0f, b2=0f, b3=0f;

  private volatile float c1=0f, c2=0f, c3=0f;

This is the [SensorActivity](https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality/blob/master/Pro%20Android%20AR%209/src/com/paar/ch9/SensorsActivity.java) where this matrix class is used.

- **Also tell me why do I need to use this 9 value matrix and which
  values need to pass to this matrix class.**

  For example in the SensorActivity why we are using angleX and angleY.

  ```
   double angleX = Math.toRadians(-90);

   double angleY = Math.toRadians(-90);

      xAxisRotation.set( 1f, 
              0f, 
              0f, 
              0f, 
              (float) Math.cos(angleX), 
              (float) -Math.sin(angleX), 
              0f, 
              (float) Math.sin(angleX), 
              (float) Math.cos(angleX));
  ```

So, what is angleX and angleY. What are all these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

you should read this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

go to **Basic rotations** in the above link to find exactly what you're looking for

in your specific example, if you compute the matrix you get the identity matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix